# Timer-Backgroundworker called from another backgroundworker-thread

Tags: c#, timer, backgroundworker, can-bus

I am currently much developing on CAN-technology in C#, and in relation to message receiption and message transmitting. So far, every message, I send, is correctly transmitted to the consumer, and every message the producer sends, will correctly be transmitted to (me as) the consumer.

Every time, a message arrives in receiption-FIFO, the _messageReceivedEvent triggers. After that the handling of one or more received messages will start. After message-handling, an existing timer (separate thread) should be resetted. This means, if no message arrives within 5 seconds, the timer-thread won't be resetted, and if elapsing, timer-thread should signal, that it has been elapsed and should set one parameter (_isDataCommunicationStillAlive) to 'FALSE'.

**Main-Thread** (that calls MessageReceiption-Backgroundworker):

```
private Timer _commTimer;


public void MessageReceiption()
{
    _quitMessageObservation = false;

    // Generate and call new DataCommunicationTimer as Backgroundworker
    DataCommunicationTimer();

    BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgWorker.DoWork += ObservingMessageReceiptionFifo;
    bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += ObservingMessageReceiptionCompleted;
    bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}


// Observes, if a new message arrived in receiption-FIFO
public void ObservingMessageReceiptionFifo(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    do
    {
      // If a new message arrives in my receiption-FIFO
      if (_messageReceivedEvent.WaitOne(100, false))
      {
         /////// Here would be code, to handle received message(s) ///////

         _isDataCommunicationStillAlive = true;

         // After message receiption, resetting timer should begin.
         // So if no new message arrives within 5 seconds, the 
         // timer counts down, and if elapsed, TimeElapsedEvent
         // should trigger and do some more stuff, like setting 
         // a boolean parameter (_isDataCommunicationStillAlive) 
         // to 'FALSE'.
         RunningDataCommTimer(sender, e);
      }

    } while (_quitMessageObservation == false);

    e.Result = "MessageReceiptionTerminated";
}


private void ObservingMessageReceiptionCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result.Equals("MessageReceiptionTerminated"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Observing message-receiption terminated.");            
    }
}
```

**DataCommunicationTimer** (as Backgroundworker (called from MessageReceiption)):

```
public void DataCommunicationTimer()
{
    _commTimer = new Timer();

    // Registers new TimeElapsedEvent
    _commTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimeElapsedEvent);

    BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgWorker.DoWork += RunningDataCommTimer;
    bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}


public void RunningDataCommTimer(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while(_isConnected == true)
    {
       // Set the Interval to 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds).
       _commTimer.Interval = 5000;
       _commTimer.Enabled = true;
       _commTimer.Start();
    }
}


public void TimeElapsedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    _isDataCommunicationStillAlive = false;
    _commTimer.Elapsed -= TimeElapsedEvent;
}
```

The problem is, that my Timer-Backgroundworker isn't working understandable, because, it terminates within one second. Another problem is, that I don't know, how to readout a specific Timer-instance regarding to remaining time...

Based on these lines of code, I cannot find the bug(s). :((

Could you please help me?!

Comment: *"because, it terminates within one second..."*. Well, looking at your *RunningDataCommTimer* method in **DataCommunicationTimer**, it become clear that it will terminate in **a few microseconds**, because all what that method does is adding an event handler to an event and setting three property values. Then it exits and with it exits the background worker.

Comment: In your Main-Thread, **ObservingMessageReceiptionFifo** will more or less exit immediately after the 0.1s wait of _messageReceivedEvent.WaitOne expired  unless *_quitMessageObservation* is `false`. When do you set *_quitMessageObservation* to false? Yepp, in the handler for the *bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted* event. Guess when this event is being triggered...

Comment: *RunningDataCommTimer(...)* is supposed to be called many times during the loop inside ObservingMessageReceiptionFifo, correct? Why do you add the same event handler again and again to the *commTimer.Elapsed event*? That does not make any sense... What was your intention there? Did you want to restart the timer?

Comment: Hey elgonzo, first I say thank you for your help. __quitMessageObservation will be set to FALSE, when user clicks on disconnect button.

Comment: I don't know, where to add the ElapsedEventHandler else.

Comment: *"__quitMessageObservation will be set to FALSE, when user clicks on disconnect button."* with this information you can certainly deduce how many iterations the do-while loop in ObservingMessageReceiptionFifo will do before the loop is being exited...

Comment: *"I don't know, where to add the ElapsedEventHandler else"*. If you don't know that, then it is time for you to back away from this programming attempt and sit down with paper and pencil and contemplate some time about the logic and flow of the program you try to code...